# invalid dateinput output format

Tags: r, datetime, shiny

While creating a shiny app to get a data frame according to user input, i use the following, which works perfectly fine:

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  textInput("name", "Comnnay Name"),

  textInput("income", "Income"),

  textInput("expenditure", "Expenditure"),

  dateInput("date", h3("Date input"),value = Sys.Date()  , min = "0000-01-01",
            max = Sys.Date(), format = "dd/mm/yy"),

  #Table showing what is there in the data frame
  tableOutput("table"),
  #Button which appends row to the existing dataframe
  actionButton("Action", "Submit"),

  #Button to save the file
  downloadButton('downloadData', 'Download')


)

library(shiny)


server <- function(input, output){
  #Global variable to save the data
  Data <- data.frame()

  Results <- reactive(data.frame(input$name, input$income, input$expenditure,
                                 input$date , Sys.Date()))  

  #To append the row and display in the table when the submit button is clicked
  observeEvent(input$Action,{
    #Append the row in the dataframe
    Data <<- rbind(Data,Results()) 
    #Display the output in the table
    output$table <- renderTable(Data)
  })



  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(

    # Create the download file name
    filename = function() {
      paste("data-", Sys.Date(), ".csv", sep="")
    },
    content = function(file) {

      write.csv(Data, file)         # put Data() into the download file
      })                          

}                                                                                  

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

But when i press the submit button it does not print the date in the format i want
[image]

What do i do to change the output version. Or do i have to specify something specially? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All dates in most languages are numeric, which is expected. If you want the string simply parse into it

```
 Results <- reactive(data.frame(input$name, input$income, input$expenditure,
                                 as.character(input$date), as.character(Sys.Date())))
```